# DPDK(20.8) Segmentation fault: While executing rte_ip_frag_table_create for IP reassemble

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dpdk

I am new to DPDK and writing the code in c++ language, currently working on IP reassembling the packets below is my sample code which is giving me segmentation fault for rte_ip_frag_table_create, I am unable to debug the issue. Much appreciated if some one can explain me where did I go wrong and how to do it in proper manner. At the moment I am finding it difficult. Thanks in advance.

> AnonHugePages:    407552 kB
>
> ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
>
> HugePages_Total:      10
>
> HugePages_Free:       10
>
> HugePages_Rsvd:        0
>
> HugePages_Surp:        0
>
> Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
>
> Hugetlb:        10485760 kB

```
#define BUFFER_RING_SIZE 65536
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1500
#define POOL_SIZE 8192
#define POOL_CACHE_SIZE 256

#define DEF_FLOW_NUM    0x1000
#define DEF_FLOW_TTL    MS_PER_S
#define IP_FRAG_TBL_BUCKET_ENTRIES  4
static uint32_t max_flow_num = DEF_FLOW_NUM;
static uint32_t max_flow_ttl = DEF_FLOW_TTL;
#define RTE_LOGTYPE_IP_RSMBL RTE_LOGTYPE_USER1

struct lcore_queue_conf {
        struct rte_ip_frag_tbl *frag_tbl;
        struct rte_ip_frag_death_row death_row; 
} __rte_cache_aligned; 


static inline int setup_queue_tbl(struct lcore_queue_conf *qconf)
{
    uint64_t frag_cycles = (rte_get_tsc_hz() + MS_PER_S - 1) / MS_PER_S * max_flow_ttl;
    qconf->frag_tbl = rte_ip_frag_table_create(max_flow_num, IP_FRAG_TBL_BUCKET_ENTRIES, max_flow_num, frag_cycles, rte_socket_id());
    if((qconf->frag_tbl) == NULL){ 
        RTE_LOG(ERR, IP_RSMBL, "Table Failed.");
        return -1;
    }   
    return 0;
}

static int
lcore_main()
{
    struct lcore_queue_conf *qconf;

    if(setup_queue_tbl(qconf) != 0)
    rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));

.
.
.
.

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct rte_mempool *mbuf_pool;
    struct rte_ring *ring;
    uint16_t portcheck;

     /* catch ctrl-c so we can print on exit */
    signal(SIGINT, int_handler);

    /* EAL setup */
    ret=rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    cout << "=====================================================" << endl;
    if(ret < 0)
        cout << EAL initialising failed." <<  strerror(-ret) << endl;
    else
        cout << EAL initialisation success." << endl;

    /* Mempool creation */
    
    mbuf_pool=rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("BUFFER", POOL_SIZE, POOL_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());

    if(mbuf_pool== NULL)
    rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
.
.
.
.
    /* Master core call */  
    lcore_main();

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
EAL: Detected 12 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_ixgbe (8086:15d1) device: 0000:01:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
=====================================================
EAL initialisation success.
PORT 0: Ethernet configuration success.
TX queue configuration success.
RX queue configuration success.
PORT 0: NIC started successfully.
PORT 0: Enabled promiscuous mode.
MAC Addr b4:96:91:3f:21:b6
=====================================================
USER1: rte_ip_frag_table_create: allocated of 6291584 bytes at socket 0
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: have you tried running under `gdb` or opening the core file under gdb?. Immedidate cause can be narrowed down to `struct lcore_queue_conf *qconf` in `lcore_man`. Without allocating any memory for the structure you are accessing `qconf->frag_tbl`. Please debug the snippet.
`

Comment: Thank you... after assigning memory to each lcore the issue resolved.

Comment: Sure, next time please format and add necessary debug. It will lot more helpful